# Why does blowfish code written in php give different results in Python?

Tags: python, php, mcrypt, blowfish

I am not very skilled in encrypting and I have been using the php code I mentioned below for encrypting for a long time. Now I want to program the same code with python, but I couldn't find a solution.

```php
<?PHP
  $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
  $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
  $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, "secret", 
  utf8_encode('changeme'), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
  echo $encrypted_string;
?>
```

results: **c811f6fe09f61abcf57623fc43554a17**

I expected the code I specified below to give the same result, but the results are not the same, what could be the reason for this?

```py
def PKCS5Padding(string):
    byteNum = len(string)
    packingLength = 8 - byteNum % 8
    appendage = chr(packingLength) * packingLength
    return string + appendage

def enc(string):
    key = b'secret'
    c1 = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_ECB)
    packedString = PKCS5Padding(string)
    return c1.decrypt(packedString.encode())
print(hashlib.md5(enc('changeme')).hexdigest())
```

results: **08c74df87caf3ed8456f0e01a4b7234b**

Comment: Note how the python code says "PKCS5 padding" several places, and the PHP code does not.

Comment: seemingly in the PHP you use `secret` as the key but in Python it is `b'secret'`...? Admittedly I have minimal knowledge of Python but this does seem like a major difference?

Comment: Also mcycpt has been unmaintained for years and was removed from PHP. Also ECB is the worst possible cipher mode.

Comment: In PHP you create a random initialization vector, therefore I doubt that the result would be the same if you run the PHP code multiple times.

Comment: Also misuse of `utf8_encode()`. At best it is a no-op, at worst it will break when fed a non-ascii value. Get rid of it. PHP has no internal string encoding.

Comment: @Sammitch Results don't match even without PKCS5 padding, I started using this code years ago and I have data created with this php code. I have to generate the same md5 code with python as this php code is generated, I can't change the php code.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Nope. always gives the same result.

Comment: If `$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);` "always gives the same result" then your system is deeply fucked.

Comment: @miken32 thanks for reply.     ibrahim@ibrahim-desktop:~$ php -v
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Mar  2 2022 15:36:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Comment: @miken32 ibrahim@ibrahim-desktop:~$ cat /var/www/html/project/java/pass.php
<?php
if (!empty($argv[1])) {
 echo md5(encrypt($argv[1]));
}
function encrypt($pure_string)
    {
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, "secret", utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        //echo $encrypted_string;
        return $encrypted_string;

 }

Comment: @miken32 ibrahim@ibrahim-desktop:~$ php /var/www/html/bbrain/java/pass.php changeme
e3b3884a2e3986a01b8d750f9d724ff8ibrahim@ibrahim-desktop:~$ php /var/www/html/bbrain/java/pass.php changeme
e3b3884a2e3986a01b8d750f9d724ff8ibrahim@ibrahim-desktop:~$ php /var/www/html/bbrain/java/pass.php changeme
e3b3884a2e3986a01b8d750f9d724ff8ibrahim@ibrahim-desktop:~$ php /var/www/html/bbrain/java/pass.php changeme
e3b3884a2e3986a01b8d750f9d724ff8ibrahim@ibrahim-desktop:~$ php /var/www/html/bbrain/java/pass.php changeme
e3b3884a2e3986a01b8d750f9d724ff8

Comment: ECB doesn't use an IV, so while `$iv` will differ between runs, it doesn't change the encrypted result.

Comment: Thank you @yut23, I solved this with your help;
     hashlib.md5(Blowfish.new(b"secret", Blowfish.MODE_ECB).encrypt("changeme")).hexdigest()
and
md5(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, "secret", utf8_encode('changeme'), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB))
same thing. thank you endlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `c1.decrypt()` in the Python code instead of `c1.encrypt()`, and the PHP code (inside `mcrypt_encrypt()`) just pads the plaintext to a multiple of 8 bytes with null bytes. The following gives the same result as the PHP code: `md5(0x9da1192c5d3b3072) == 0xe3b3884a2e3986a01b8d750f9d724ff8`

```python
def enc(plaintext):
    key = b'secret'
    c1 = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_ECB)
    encoded = plaintext.encode()
    padded = encoded.ljust((len(encoded) + 7) // 8 * 8, b'\0')
    return c1.encrypt(padded)
```